# Attribute Hierarchy: Parent-Child Relationship?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

Is it possible to create a parent-child relationship with attributes?

A typical example is a list of base colours and you also want to specify their supplier names:

brown 
--- walnut 
--- chocolate 
grey 
--- grey melange 
--- charcoal 
blue 
--- navy
--- powder blue

Ideally, you want the base colours appearing in any layered navigation/filters.